# IONIC 1 SERVE -L command giving me an error on browser

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

When i run "ionic serve -l" i get an error as per the picture below, can anyone help please.
[Ionic serve -l results on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjD3o.png)

[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toIxT.png)

Comment: Did you try with the port number 8100?

Comment: This is interesting. Why the Ip is not localhost address,.

Comment: As you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0), 0.0.0.0 is `a non-routable meta-address`. You cannot access it via browser. Also, please post your cmd code as (formatted) text, not as a link to a print screen image.

Comment: It's working i just had to make localhost i.e http://127.0.0.1:8100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use 0.0.0.0 in browser

Use http://localhost:8100 or http://127.0.0.1:8100